What are the benefits of buried engines?
I recently came over the de Havilland Comet, and I found an interesting feature of the aircraft: it had four engines, and all of them seemed it be embedded inside the aircraft wings. I later research about the topic, and found that they are called "buried engines". Here's a photo to better illustrate the concept:
image of de Haviland comet wing section with buried engines
Wikipedia says that "This design reduces both drag and the risk of ingesting foreign objects, but increases the difficulty of maintenance and complicates the wing structure."1. However,

I'm not sure about Wikipedia's credibility.
Wikipedia's definition is a bit too vague and broad, can anyone please explain specifically what the benefits/downsides are?

So, my question can be summarized as follows:

What specifically are the benefits of buried engines?
What specifically are the downsides of buried engines?
Why are buried engines much less common in civilian aircraft today to the point of almost never seen? I do know that some military aircraft, especially stealth bombers, have buried engines, but nearly all civilian aircraft dropped buried engines in favor of podded engines. So, why?

I appreciate any explanations! Thanks in advance!

The wiki article is not bad. It was just a bad idea in practical terms outside of specialized cases.
Buried engines play havoc with the design of wing spars because the engine and/or its ducting must accommodate the spar beam (a big hole in it typically). Doing so makes the spar quite a bit heavier. Same problem with accessibility. You need to make the bottom of the wing plank, the primary bending structure in modern torsion box wings, with a big hole in it to allow access to the engine from below or to remove it. Add it all up and the structural issues combined with poor accessibility more than cancels out any benefit drag wise.
And thus like so many ideas that look great on paper but not in the real world, it's rarely done. You stick the engines on pylons, on the wings or at the tail. Easy to get at and remove/install, and light and the wing can be a simple uninterrupted box structure.
Putting them on pylons on the wings lets them be used as counter balances for the wing itself, to move its torsional (twisting) axis forward and reducing the stiffness required of the wing box. This is why the pylons project forward. Boeing learned this on the B-47 program as they had to deal with aerolasticity problems with long flexible swept wings.

Thanks for your answer. Your answer is great and answers all of my questions. Thank you very much!

Additionally, the Comet used turbojet engines.  Newer aircraft use high-bypass turbo-fan engines.  These have a much larger diameter, so all the of the above become even more significant!
